# Access to the table fields after passing it [sqlite/c#]

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite

How can i get acces to my fields after passing whole record as result of the function?
I would like to do the same thing in TEST() function as in GetRecord function - the commented line

```
    public void TEST()
{
    var x = GetRecord(1,1);
    Button.Text = ????
}
   public async Task<Questions> GetRecord(int actualLevel, int actualLanguage)
   SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("QuestionDatabase.db");
   Random rnd = new Random();
   var query = await conn.Table<Questions>().Where(x => x.FK_ID_DifficultyLevel == actualLevel && x.FK_ID_Languages == actualLanguage).ToListAsync();
   int r = rnd.Next(query.Count);
   //Button.Text = query.ElementAt(r).Question;  <- How to make the same thing in main after passing result?
   return query.ElementAt(r);
}
```

The function above is connecting to the database and passing random record.(which foreign key for language and lvl = some int value).
The record have fields like:
- Question, answer

and i want paste the strings from this fields into button text field.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on:

http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

I was getting Deadlock, the function call need to be `await`